# How to write these constraints in Cplex

Tags: cplex

I am writing a model to minimize overall cost but I faced a problem when I wanted to write off-days constraints, the constraints are shown in the attached picture. My question is how to write these constraints in Cplex?

[Off-days constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XVlp.png)
*Click on the hyperlink to open the constraints pictures.

w: stands for workers
s: stands for shifts
d: stands for days

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical constraints:

```
int  n=10;
range Days=1..n;

dvar boolean X[Days];
dvar boolean O[Days];

subject to
{
  forall(d in Days:d+1<=n) (O[d]==1)=>(0==sum(i in d..d+1) X[i]);
  forall(d in Days:d+6<=n) (O[d]==1)=>(0==sum(i in d+1..d+6) X[i]);
}
```